# Why does this code usually work but sometimes produce Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**************************************************
a is a pointer to an array of strings
b is a string
This function appends b to *a
n is the number of strings currently "held" by *a
**************************************************/
int append(char ***a, char *b, unsigned long n) {
    if (a && *a && **a) {
        char** tmp = realloc(*a, (n + 1) * sizeof(**a));
        if (tmp) {
            tmp[n] = b;
            *a = tmp;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void test() {
    char *words[7] = { "food", "is", "good", "to", "eat,", "like", "pizza" };
    char** a = malloc(1 * sizeof(*a));

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        append(&a, words[i], i);
        int j = 0; 
        while (j <= i) 
            printf("%s ", a[j++]); 
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

The code always compiles fine and without warnings. And the executable runs as expected about 95% of the time. But about 5% of the time, I get a Segmentation Fault. I know the fault occurs at `a[j++]` but I don't understand why.

Comment: If things work *"sometimes"*, there is a good bet you are invoking *Undefined Behavior*....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And segmentation fault is making this bet a definite win :)

Comment: OK, thanks guys. So where am I invoking Undefined Behavior?

Comment: Note that being a [3-Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) it not a compliment.  You'd probably do better to create a structure to hold the array of pointers, along with the allocated size and the size in use.  You can then avoid incrementing the size of the array by one; that can lead to very poor performance (quadratic behaviour) as data is copied around as you reallocate memory.  However, that's not the immediate cause of the crash.

Comment: Also, note this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/zvsaK8OwfthbmY7U

Comment: Thanks @Bob__. I just get "Failed at 0"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
if (a && *a && **a)
```

When you `malloc` space for one element initially pointed at by `a`, you never actually initialize that memory. As a result, `**a` is uninitialized, so reading it is considered undefined behavior. In practice, I suspect that sometimes the memory that's allocated to you is a null pointer in some cases but not others, which accounts for the flakiness.

I don't actually think you even need the checks on `*a` and `**a`. As long as the pointer `a` itself isn't a null pointer, you can modify the pointer that it points at (`*a`). Moreover, knowing whether the first element of the array pointed at by `*a` is null (`**a`) isn't actually needed here. So you can just replace this check with

```
if (a)
```

I would go further and not even allocate an initial array for `a`, since you're never actually going to read the value that's stored there.

Other things to do: the function `append` returns a status code that informs whether the operation succeeded or failed. It would be a good idea to check that value whenever calling `append` just in case it fails. You might also want to change the outer `if` statement into an `assert` so that if someone calls it with bad parameters, it halts and reports a violation of the preconditions rather than failing with an error code. After all, if the issue is "you gave me arguments that couldn't possibly be right," it means there's a logic error somewhere in the code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much @templatetypedef! I never initialize that memory. And I think you're also right about not needing to allocate an initial array for ```a```. Please give me some time to experiment with this before marking this as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you again @templatetypedef. Your answer and "other things to do" are really helpful. I also started looking at the content on your websites and found it to be very helpful and fun. Thanks!